# SetInterval inside nested functions in JS is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JS and trying to implement the `setInterval` inside the functions in Js.

JS:

```
var tar = document.getElementById("sample");
function dataSample(tar) {
    
   //setInterval variable

   var sInt = [];

   function setIntv(tar) {
     sInt[tar] = setInterval(function() {
        var currentDate = Date.now();
        var value = String(currentDate).substr(8, 2)
   }, 1000);
   console.log(sInt[tar]);
  }
 setIntv(tar);
}
dataSample(tar);
```

I need the 2 digit values to be **updated every 1s** using **setInterval**. *But, It didnt work.*

`Console.log displays 1000`.  The `setInterval Id(sInt[])` should display the values periodically, so that `console.log(sInt[]);` should display the updated values every 1s.

`How to make setInterval work inside the function ?`

Could someone please help?

Many thanks.

Comment: @SebastianSimon edited the code. When setIntv[tar] is called outside the function it should display the values every 1s.

Comment: In your code, `dataSample` is only called once; within it, `setIntv` is only called once; within it, `console.log` is only called once. `value` is also never used. So what exactly is supposed to periodically display anything?

Comment: @sebastian simon, the setInterval variable `sInt[tar]` is supposed to display the values periodically.. How can I do this? Could you please help? Many thanks.

Comment: A variable doesn’t do anything on its own. Have you tried putting the `console.log` statement — the one that actually displays anything — inside the `setInterval` callback?

Comment: var sInt = [];
 function setIntv(tar) {
     sInt[tar] = setInterval(function() {
        var currentDate = Date.now();
        var value = String(currentDate).substr(8, 2)
   }, 1000);
    console.log(sInt[tar]);  } Here console.log(sInt[tar]) gives 1000.

Answer (score 0):

console.log() shows you instance of interval, which, in your case, is identified with number 1000. If you want print values, you need to put console.log(value) inside interval function

instead of this:

```js
function setIntv(tar) {
     sInt[tar] = setInterval(function() {
        var currentDate = Date.now();
        var value = String(currentDate).substr(8, 2)
   }, 1000);
   console.log(sInt[tar]);
}
```

write this:

```js
function setIntv(tar) {
     sInt[tar] = setInterval(function() {
        var currentDate = Date.now();
        var value = String(currentDate).substr(8, 2);
        console.log(value);
   }, 1000);
}
```

or if you need to acces this value outside of interval function (despite your comment):

```js
function setIntv(tar) {
     setInterval(function() {
        var currentDate = Date.now();
        var value = String(currentDate).substr(8, 2);
        sInt[tar] = value;
   }, 1000);
}

console.log(sInt[tar]);
```

Comment: I need the `sInt[tar]` setInterval variable should display the values periodically.  When I call `setIntv[tar]` somewhere outside the function, it should display the values every 1S.

Comment: not sure what exactly you want, but I've added new example to my answer. Try if this is what you need

Comment: I need the setInterval variable `sInt[tar]` to display the values periodically and the values should be stored in `sInt[tar]`.  The values should be updated periodically , even  if the function with `sInt[]` called anywhere.

Comment: Even if I use like the below code. I could see the console.log() with the static values,. The value is `not updated  every 1s`. It remains static.                              
 var sInt = [];
 var currentDate = Date.now();
var value = String(currentDate).substr(8, 2);
   function setIntv(tar) {
     sInt[tar] = setInterval(value, 1000);
     console.log(sInt[tar]);
  } Could you please help? I couldn't find what is the error here? Many thanks